# How to specify the (sub)directory for source and compiled files when evaluating Java codeblocks in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, java

I use Org Mode with Java codeblocks.
When I evaluate a codeblock the source files and the compiled files (*.class) are saved in the same directory as the Org file with the codeblocks.

How can I change the directory, where the source and compiled files are saved?